# Sound stops working when training neural networks on GPU

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, sound, cuda

When I start training neural networks on my system with Ubuntu 16.04 on a cuda GPU, random disturbance sounds come through the headphones and eventually within 5 mins I can not hear an of the audio I am playing and only the disturbance stays.

It doesn't tend to happen when GPU usage is minimal around less than 30%, but beyond it does.

What I have tried so far: (Nothing has helped)

- Reinstalling different CUDA driver
- Trying a different machine learning framework (tensorflow, pytorch, torch)
- Trying a different GPU (Tried TITAN Black and 1080TI so far)

Comment: Are you outputting audio through HDMI/DP on the GPU (and then to your headphones)?

Comment: @fakedad The HDMI from the GPU connects to the monitor, while I have headphones connected to the audio port on the PC case